# Bind double-click from everywhere on a wx.PyControl

Tags: python, events, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm creating a clickable image (with text+bitmap) widget class as a subclass of `wx.PyControl`.  I want to bind double-click **anywhere on this widget** (on text, on bitmap, on background) to some action  (called `OnClick` here).

Unfortunately, it doesn't work : with this code, `OnClick` is not called, when I click on the bitmap or text part of the `MyBitmapButton` widget. (See question below).

```
import wx

class MyBitmapButton(wx.PyControl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=-1, bmp=None, label='blah', pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size=(166,220),
                 style = 0, validator = wx.DefaultValidator,
                 name = "mybitmapbutton"):
        style |= wx.BORDER_NONE 
        wx.PyControl.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style, validator, name)
        myimg = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, bmp, pos=(8,8), size=(150,150))
        mytxt = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label, (6,165))

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, size=(800,600))
        sizer = wx.WrapSizer()

        img = wx.Image('background.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(img)
        btn = MyBitmapButton(self, -1, bmp, label='a')

        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.Sizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, 8)
        self.Show()

        # ################
        # Why don't these bindings detect double-click anywhere on the widget ?
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnClick)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnClick, btn)

    def OnClick(self, event):
        print 'Clicked'

app = wx.App(0)
frame = MainFrame(None, 'Test')
app.MainLoop()
```

**How to bind double-click on anywhere on the button to** `OnClick` **?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magical solution, you need to call `Bind()` on `myimg` and `mytxt` as well. Of course, you can do it inside `MyBitmapButton` to encapsulate this inside your custom control, i.e. bind to the double clicks on its sub-controls and forward them to the button itself -- then your existing `btn.Bind()` would be enough.

The only (ugly) alternative is to handle events at `wx.App` level as it gets all of them and, in principle, you could check if the double click comes from a main frame child and then handle it. But this is bad practice and I don't recommend doing it.

Comment: Thank you @VZ. Do you have a sample code to add inside `MyBitmapButton`in order to bind double-clicks on the sub-controls, in order that I can do a unique binding in  `MainFrame`'s `__init__` ?

Comment: How to make that I can do the binding in `MainFrame` ?
(as `class MyBitmapButton(wx.PyControl)` is a generic class, I cannot do each specific binding in the definition of `MyBitmapButton`...)

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have any sample Python code. But it should be simple enough: provide your own `BindToDClick(func)` in `MyBitmapButton` and call `self.Bind(func)`, `myimg.Bind(func)` and `mytext.Bind(func)` from it.